# PyMysql encoding issue

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, encoding, pymysql

I have MySql database (MyISAM engine, utf-8 charset and utf8_general_ci collation). Also I use PyMysql driver to connect my Python3 code to that database.
But when I am trying to fetch some rows with following code

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                       port=3306,
                       user='root',
                       passwd='',
                       db='db_name')

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM my_table')
print(cur.description)
print()
for row in cur:
   print(row)
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

I have bad output for Russian column

> (1, '???????????????????????????????')

I have tried to provide different parameters such as **use_unicode**, **charset** but none of their combinations do not bring desired result. With English columns all is ok. So how can I get well-encoded string?
Output of *create table* command

> 'CREATE TABLE `my_table` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `ruColumn` varchar(155) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
>   ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'

Comment: please show the output from `show create table my_table`

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways that could have happened.

- Your bytes in your client were not utf8-encoded.
- You did not specify `utf8` when connecting to the database.  This is done via `set_charset('utf8')`, `SET NAMES utf8`, or some other client-specific method.  (What client are you using?)

The data is lost.  Delete the data from the tables.  (The table definition is ok.)  So, clean up the code and start over.

For more details on Python, see [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python).

Comment: I am using [pymysql](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) and specifying charset doesn't work, the same with executing `SET NAMES utf8` on cursor object

Comment: Do it on the connection; see my link.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by switching connection driver from pymysql to [mysql-connector-python](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation.html)
You can install it via pip

```
pip install mysql-connector-python --allow-external mysql-connector-python
```

So change the code to

```
import mysql
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                               port=3306,
                               user='root',
                               passwd='',
                               db='db_name')
```

and output will be correct without additional specifying of *charset* or other params.
Seems like it's internal encoding problem of PyMySQL driver.